# Xtrareports - report header problems

Tags: devexpress

i have a report in .repx format. with a group header , detail and group footer.

The problem is when no more space for group footer on first page , the group footer is printed on next page , but on this page is printed the group header too , even if there's no more records in detail section . How can i do that if no more records in detail section the group header to be invisible on next page.

Thank you !

Comment: how could that possible.. if there are no group of record then how can you make a group to print in the report??? elaborate and simplify your question..

Comment: all the records are printed on first page , but there 's no more space to print the group footer , and the footer is printed on next page but the group header is printed too.i want that on second page the group header to be invisible if no more records on detail section.

Comment: then use before print event and check whether it is page 2.. if yes then suppress the group header..  i presume that your report will not exceed count of page to 2.

Comment: but on some cases , there are records on page 2 and i need the group header in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [How do I hide the GroupFooterBand when the grouping field is empty or null?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q311702.aspx)

There are two approaches to achieve this, but i suggest you to follow as below:

> If you can find out which detail bands will be hidden in the
>   GroupHeaderBand.BeforePrint and GroupFooterBand.BeforePrint event
>   handlers, then you can hide corresponding group header and footer.

References:
[Hide GroupHeader & GroupFooter](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q295143.aspx)
**[source from the report.]**
[How to shrink groupHeader or to hide a xrtable in the groupHeader - don't work](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q355774.aspx)
[suppress group footer if group header is suppressed](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ19826.aspx)
[How to hide GroupFooterBand on the last page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q230489.aspx)
[GroupFooter BeforePrint with Hierarchical data structure](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q382573.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with for nearly an identical problem was to keep track of a counter that resets on each page.

First, wire up `BeforePrint` on the `TopMargin` band, which prints on every page:

```
private int detailsPrintedThisPage = 0;
private void TopMargin_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    detailsPrintedThisPage = 0;
}
```

Next, whenever a detail prints, keep track of that:

```
private void Details_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    detailsPrintedThisPage++;
}
```

Finally, on the group footer, if no details have printed this page, then suppress the footer:

```
private void GroupFooter1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
   e.Cancel = (detailsPrintedThisPage == 0);
}
```

The problem I was solving was initially the same as yours, except that my group footer was nothing but a blank label meant to provide padding between groups.  The blank spacing was causing an entire page to print (with a group header) on the last page if the details lined up just right to be wrong, which is exactly the case you describe.

In my case, however, I simplified the problem by removing the footer altogether and added extra space before the group header that I suppressed if it was the first group header printed on a given page.  However the code above is adapted from my solution to where it should work in the more general case you describe where you want to hide the group footer specifically if there are no details on the page.  Sharing 7 years late in case it helps someone else who lands here...